# Check if columns in csv is > or < in given max

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How can I give warning and don't proceed to command if column in csv is less than or greater than than 4. I have this code to import my csv but I only need 4 columns to avoid unwanted insertion of values to mysql.

```
 while(($csvdata = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","))!== FALSE){
        if($i>0) {
    $sha1 = $csvdata[0];
    $vsdt = $csvdata[1];
    $trendx  = $csvdata[2];
    $notes  = $csvdata[3];

    // Get record where sha1 
    $check_sha = "SELECT sha1 FROM jeremy_table_test WHERE sha1='".$sha1."'";
    $check_shaquery = mysqli_query($con , $check_sha);
    if($check_shaquery){
        $sha_count = mysqli_num_rows($check_shaquery);
    }

    // Check if sha1 already in database
    if(isset($sha_count) && $sha_count>0){
        $sql = "UPDATE `jeremy_table_test` SET `date_sourced`='".$date."',`sha1`='".$sha1."',`vsdt`='".$vsdt."',`trendx`='".$trendx."',`notes`='".$notes."' WHERE sha1='".$sha1."'";
        $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test (date_sourced,sha1,vsdt,trendx,notes) VALUES ('$date','$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx','$notes')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);
    }

    $c = $c+1;
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    }
        $i++;
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    }
```

Please give me some idea on how to do this. It's my only problem

Comment: simply use `if count($csvdata) !== 4 {..throw exception..}`

Comment: it keeps on executing the command, where exactly should i put the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function at the beginning of your `while {..}` loop.

```
while(($csvdata = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","))!== FALSE){

    // If count of the array is not equal to 4
    if ( count($csvdata) !== 4 ) {

        // Throw exception and exit.
        throw new Exception("Invalid CSV file. Column count not matching!");
        exit();
    }

....
```